# How to send cURL request to Laravel App via Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, laravel-valet

I'm using Guzzle within my Laravel app to make a request to /oauth/token/ as a login request and see to be getting connection refused

My code in my custom controller is:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        try {
            $response = $http->post("https://mixapp.test/oauth/token/", [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                    'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                    'username' => $request->username,
                    'password' => $request->password,
                ]
            ]);
            return $response->getBody();
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
                return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
            } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
                return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
            }
            return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
        }
    }
```

And the error seems to be:

> local.ERROR: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to mixapp.test port 443: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) {"exception":"[object] (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 7: Failed to connect to mixapp.test port 443: Connection refused

Both are be on https, and I am using laravel valet.

Comment: Are you able to manually post to that address using curl or some REST extension?

Comment: Yep, works fine when I hit that endpoint directly via postman.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up solving this. Thinking a bit harder about it, I was just calling the same server from the controller, so I changed my guzzle request to:

```
$response = $http->post("https://127.0.0.1/oauth/token/", [...
```

Thanks SO for being my rubber duck :)